# Trouble Saving Multiplied Matrix Value into Vector

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I am having trouble saving my multiplied matrix values into my result vector.  I am not sure how to go about saving the values into the correct position on the matrix.  First I made a matrix with blank values but that ran into an issue with overwriting their values using a temp variable.  Then I tried to store them using " resultTemp[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]" but then I get an error saying that it is not a vector even though I thought I declare it as such :/

```
vector<vector <int> > mat1;    //This is how my teacher said to save them
vector<vector <int> > mat2;
vector<vector <int> > resultMat;


      for(int i=0; i<resRows;i++){  //Try to store "0" value into vector first
            vector <int> temp;
            int tempVal=0;
            for(int j=0; j< resCols; j++){
                temp.push_back(tempVal);
            }
            resultMat.push_back(temp);

 for(int i = 0; i < rows1; ++i){
     vector <int> resultTemp;
     int product = 0;
         for(int j = 0; j < cols2; ++j){
             product=0;
             for(int k = 0; k < cols1; ++k)
             {
                 //product += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];  
                 //resultTemp.push_back(product);       
                 // commented out while trying to debug
                 // Gives me good value but not saving right

                 resultTemp[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j].  
                 //Error: says result temp not a array, pointer, or vector

                 //resultMat.push_back(prodTemp);
                 //This won't overwrite just add onto vector?
             }
         cout << product << endl;
    }
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Ask yourself: what should `v[i][j]` mean for `vector<int> v;`? `v[i]` will give you an `int` value, then what should `[j]` do?

Comment: Thinking it would be the index in which the product was being saved? :/

Comment: You have a 1D vector, but 2 indices...

Comment: so is that an unnecessary index value? Am i thinking too hard about the dimension of the vector?

Comment: getting a seg fault when I change it. So do i need to save it outside of that loop maybe?

Comment: You're trying to index twice into 1D array. First, you get an `int`, second, you get a compile error because indexing into an `int` is meaningless. You get a segfault because `resultTemp` is empty and you can't access its elements with `[...]`.

Comment: hmm so should i go back to my original plan of using the initial resultMat?

Comment: Yes, once you have created `resultMat` at the correct size and with all zeros, there is no need for any more temporary vectors. Just `resultMat[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]`

Comment: I was having issues with trying to use resultMat[i] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j] as well.  Is it okay that I initialized with 0s?

Comment: Incidentally there an easier way to create `resultMat`. Just `vector<vector<int>> resultMat(resRows, vector <int>(resCols));`

Comment: @101001 What issues were you having? I guess you have some issue with the number of rows and columns not being calculated correctly.

Comment: Now I think I have to overload "+=" which i may need to touch up on.   I thought the rows and columns were being calculated right.  Maybe its messed up somewhere in the loop

Comment: @101001 No, you are adding and multiplying integers so `+=` doesn't need overloading. I think you must be overthinking things

Comment: If you have a matrix of the right size then `m[i][j]` will access the given element of that matrix. And you can just copy what you would see for matrix multiplication in math textbook. That's all there is to it.

Comment: The error told me it needed to be overloaded when I compiled it :/